# How to resove Can't locate IO/Zlib.pm in @INC error?

Tags: r, perl

I installed this library: https://www.thermofisher.com/us/en/home/life-science/microarray-analysis/microarray-analysis-partners-programs/affymetrix-developers-network/affymetrix-devnet-tools.html

using:

```
install.packages("SNPolisher_2.0.3.tar.gz",repos=NULL,type="source")
```

and I am running it using R version 3.6.3 like this:

```
> library(SNPolisher)
> Ps_Visualization(pidFile="pidfile.txt", summaryFile="brlmm-p.summary.txt" ,callFile="brlmm-p.calls.txt", confidenceFile="brlmm-p.confidences.txt")
Can't locate IO/Zlib.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /software/linux-el7-x86_64/tools/vcftools-0.1.16/installer/vcftools-vcftools-954e607/src/perl /opt/moab/lib/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at /home/anamaria/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/SNPolisher/Perl/visualization.pl line 9.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /home/anamaria/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.6/SNPolisher/Perl/visualization.pl line 9.
1 probesets in the pid file.  First 1 requested for plotting. Generating the cluster plots for 1 SNPs/probesets.


No file found for ABAFT_g_4RWG569_BI_SNP_A01_34952.CEL in the temporary directory Temp 

Note that ABAFT_g_4RWG569_BI_SNP_A01_34952.CEL file is located in Temp and I also have it in the current directory from where I’m running this.
```

pidfile.txt looks like this:

```
probeset_id
ABAFT_g_4RWG569_BI_SNP_A01_34952.CEL
```

details abotu software are here: https://assets.thermofisher.com/TFS-Assets/LSG/manuals/MAN0017790_SNPolisher_UG.pdf

UPDATE per $KjetilS. comments

```
perl -v
This is perl 5, version 16, subversion 3 (v5.16.3) built for x86_64-linux-thread-multi
(with 33 registered patches, see perl -V for more detail)

perl -MIO::Zlib -le'print$INC{"IO/Zlib.pm"}'

 Can't locate IO/Zlib.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /software/linux-el7-x86_64/tools/vcftools-0.1.16/installer/vcftools-vcftools-954e607/src/perl /opt/moab/lib/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .).
```

BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

I can not run this with “sudo” (or any other sudo commands) because I don’t have sys admin rights on this cluster:

```
sudo perl -MIO::Zlib -le'print$INC{"IO/Zlib.pm"}'

I can not find library with:

find /software/linux-el7-x86_64/tools/vcftools-0.1.16/installer/vcftools-vcftools-954e607/src/perl /opt/moab/lib/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 -wholename "*IO/Zlib.pm" -ls

find: ‘/opt/moab/lib/perl5’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/usr/local/lib64/perl5’: No such file or directory
find: ‘/usr/local/share/perl5’: No such file or directory

CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
NAME="CentOS Linux"
VERSION="7 (Core)"
ID="centos"
ID_LIKE="rhel fedora"
VERSION_ID="7"
PRETTY_NAME="CentOS Linux 7 (Core)"
```

Comment: I think your three `No such file or directory` messages are a clue that those directories aren't but should be readable to your user. You probably can't do much about it if you can't sudo, but try asking your sysadmin to run perhaps `sudo chmod -R a+rx $(perl -le'print for grep/\//,@INC')`

Answer (score 3):

I don't know R, but this looks like a Perl error message. Perl can't find the IO::Zlib module. This is unusual since IO::Zlib is a core module and thus part of any normal Perl installation since perl version 5.9.3. Things I would try:

- run `perl -v` to see if you got an older perl than 5.9.3 (highly unusual in 2020 since that version was released in 2006)
- run `find /software/linux-el7-x86_64/tools/vcftools-0.1.16/installer/vcftools-vcftools-954e607/src/perl /opt/moab/lib/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 -wholename "*IO/Zlib.pm" -ls` and check if that Zlib.pm file, if found, is readable to your current user. The dirs listed is those in your error message
- run the same command as above with `sudo`  (sudo space) in front
- `perl -MIO::Zlib -le'print$INC{"IO/Zlib.pm"}'`
- `sudo perl -MIO::Zlib -le'print$INC{"IO/Zlib.pm"}'` if the file exists, but your current user don't have read permission on it, add that permission with `chmod` (also to the above directories)
- `sudo cpan IO::Zlib` or
- `sudo cpan App::cpanminus` and `sudo cpanm IO::Zlib`
- `export PERLLIB=/some/dir:$PERLLIB` if you found the IO/Zlib.pm file, but it's not under a directory mentioned under @INC at the bottom of the output from `perl -V` The directory in PERLLIB should not be the IO-directory, but the one right above it.
- what linux version and distro are you on, perhaps

You're more likely to get good answers if you add info about which Linux version and distro you're running. On some systems this is revealed by `cat /etc/*release`

Comment: Thank you for these excellent debugging tips. I did update my post with things you proposed. Unfortunately I can not run on this cluster anything with "sudo"

Comment: If bit more cumbersome, but you could try to install another perl under your home directory without needing `sudo` rights and perhaps use that with R: `curl -L https://install.perlbrew.pl | bash` as in https://perlbrew.pl/ ... see more info there. `perlbrew init`, `perlbrew available`, `perlbrew install perl-5.30.3` (wait maybe 15 minutes), `perlbrew use perl-5.30.3` and then run your R things and see.

Comment: @anamaria, Re "*can not run on this cluster anything with "sudo"*", Perl modules can be installed without special permissions. See local::lib for a way to do that. /// But I don't like to install modules for a distro-controlled `perl` with anything but the distro's modules. So I like Kjetil's solution of installing a local `perl` you have full control over (e.g. using `perlbrew`). It's quite easy.

Comment: @Kjetil S., Re "*This is unusual since IO::Zlib is a core module and thus part of any normal Perl installation*". Unfortunately, it's all too common for linux distros to split `perl` across more than one package, leading this broken expectations such as this one. Works fine as long as you stay within the distro's ecosystem, but it's common for problems to happen if you leave it.

Comment: @ikegami I didn't realize, guess I've been lucky with the distros I've been using. Could be interesting to know why distros want "incomplete" Perls leaving out core some core modules. Maybe it's about disk space. I've often thought it would be nice if Perl could use modules from within .zip files as well. Sort of like Java. There exists tools for "mounting" zip-files.

Comment: Re "*if Perl could use modules from within .zip files as well.*", You can do that using a `@INC` hook.